# Kotlin: How to check variable with lateinit property is initialized or not

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, rx-java, reactivex

I have a variable that is declared like

```
private lateinit var apiDisposable: Disposable
```

and then in `onPause()` method, I am doing

```
override fun onPause() {
    super.onPause()
    if (!apiDisposable.isDisposed)
        apiDisposable.dispose()
}
```

But I get this

> kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property
>   apiDisposable has not been initialized

Can anyone tell me how could I check if this variable is initialized or not? Is there any method like `isInitialised()`

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Declare your property as a simple property of a nullable type:

```
private var apiDisposable: Disposable? = null
```

Call the method using the safe call notation:

```
override fun onPause() {
    super.onPause()
    apiDisposable?.dispose()
}
```

`lateinit` is reserved for variables that are guaranteed to be initialized, if this is not your case - don't use it.

Answer (score 16):

```
if(::apiDisposable.isInitialized)
```

will solve your problem.

In general,

`::<lateinit variable name>.isInitialized` is used to check if it has been initialized.

Comment: What is this variable was in a companion object?